# Deploying windows phone app from VS 2015 ends with Install failed

Tags: visual-studio-2015, deployment, windows-phone-8.1

I have one windows phone 8.1 project and I am trying to deploy it from VS 2015 Community Update 3 to my phone device ( Lumia 920), but from today it is not possible. Deploying (debug, release ) always ends with an error

```
Connecting to Device...
Installing the application...
Deployment of application to device failed.
Install failed. Please contact your software vendor.
```

It is very strange, but this project was already deployed to this phone many times, but now it is not installed in the device. When I change 'package name' in package.appxmanifest then it works, but it is not acceptable solution for me because my application is already in the store. Also I tried this with another my application and there everything is ok. So VS looks ok. I also tried to build application with old source files where everything was surely ok and now it ends with the same error, so I think it has nothing common with my latest changes. 
I already tried:
- rebuild solution, manually clean build directories, restart VS, restart device...
Do you have any solution for this problem?

Thank you.

Comment: this is the reason , may be you already installed app with this package id or name please uninstall it first .  or change PhoneProductId="-----" in package manifest right click on it in vs and click on view code

Comment: The app is not installed on device, but the latest installation of this app from store failed with error code 80073cf9.

Comment: And try to debug your app in a emulator device. If hyper v supported in your pc, are you change any one digit of your phone product id in app manifest

Comment: If above step not resolve your problem then try debug your app in release mode instead of debug and also change app version and phone product id in app manifest , if apps is installed and work on another phone or emulator than you need to clear you phone temporary files or install app to phone memory or need to reset you phone

Comment: My pc doesn't support hyper, so emulator was not possible to use. Clearing temporary files and also soft reset of phone didn't help. Changing of package name solves the problem, but the application is already in the store.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the problem started after unsuccessful installation (the installation failed with error code 80073cf9) from store so I have submitted another version of the app to the store. After installing and then installing this new app from store deploying the same application from Visual Studio started to work again. So probably some temporary files from unsuccessful installation blocked deploying from VS.